Compose ConstraintLayout's pivots aren't working as intended?
I am trying to use Compose's ConstraintLayout composable to place a composable on 30% midway through the screen from the top.
I tried using the pivotY attribute in the constraint DSL to no avail, translateY worked but I don't want to specify Dp for obvious reasons)
Here is a test composable I've tested with
@Composable
@Preview
fun Test() {
  ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().aspectRatio(1f)
  ) {
    val btn = createRef()
    Box(
      modifier = Modifier
        .size(64.dp)
        .background(Color.Red)
        .constrainAs(btn) {
        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
        top.linkTo(parent.top)
        pivotY = 30f // or -30f, none is working (same thing with 0.3f of -0.3f)
      }
    )
  }
}


If I'm not mistaken. The pivots have nothing to do with the positioning of the view, but to determine what is considered the center points for when you want to do animations

if that's the case is there another way i can position a composable in a ConstraintLayout a certain percentage from its original position?

I've found the answer in here.
found out i have to use another linkTo function
@Composable
@Preview
fun Test() {
  ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxWidth()
      .aspectRatio(1f),
  ) {
    val btn = createRef()
    Box(
      modifier = Modifier
        .size(64.dp)
        .background(Color.Red)
        .constrainAs(btn) {
          linkTo(parent.top, parent.bottom, bias = 0.3f)
        },
    )
  }
}


To place a composable at 30% from the top of the screen using Jetpack Compose's ConstraintLayout, you can use the FractionalPosition modifier to achieve this. The pivotY attribute in the constraint DSL is not the right approach for this task. Instead, you can position the element by specifying the fraction of the parent's height.
here is the example
@Composable
@Preview
fun Test() {
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .aspectRatio(1f)
) {
    val btn = createRef()
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(64.dp)
            .background(Color.Red)
            .constrainAs(btn) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            }
            .offset(y = (-0.35f * it.maxHeight).toDp()) // Positioning the box at 30% from the top
    )
}

}
 fun Float.toDp(): Dp = (this / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).dp

